# Java- Adapter design pattern implmentation variations

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

I'm new to design pattern subject area and keen to understand the implementation variations of  design patterns. I have seen the following structure for adapter class in adapter design pattern in numerous tutorials on web. (Following code sample is extracted from wikipedia )

```
public class ClassAFormat1 implements StringProvider {
    private ClassA classA = null;

    public ClassAFormat1(final ClassA A) {
        classA = A;
    }

    public String getStringData() {
        return format(classA.toString());
    }
}
```

If i'm not mistaken, ClassA is the adaptee and StringProvider is the target in this example (Classes are not provided here).

I have made a small adjustment to the above code by defining and initializing the adaptee class within the method of target. I know its strange but  want to know whether it still belongs to the adapter design pattern.

```
public class ClassAFormat1 implements StringProvider {



    public String getStringData() {

               ClassA classA = new ClassA();
        return format(classA.toString());
    }
}
```

Has the above adapter class written according to the guidelines of adapter design pattern?

Thank you.

Comment: Follow this link (It's .Net, but useful): [http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAdapter.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of adapters, is to have the ability to treat objects as if they are instances of other classes.
In the example you provided, and instance of `ClassA` can be "treated" as `StringProvider` simply by using `new ClassAFormat1(a)` where `a`'s type is `ClassA`.

With the change you added, you can't take different instances of `ClassA` and make them behave as `StringProvider`. In this case `ClassAFormat1` cannot be use as an adapter from `ClassA` to `StringProvider` (in the sence that you cannot give it any instance of `ClassA` and make it behaves like a `StringProvider`.